# C# Адекватный udp-клиент, принимающий ответ от нескольких серверов

Tags: c#, сокет, udp

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать более менее адекватный клиент на udp. Смысл задачи заключается в следующем:

1. Клиент отправляет широковещательный udp-запрос на порт 111 (если быть конкретнее, то запрос portmapper`у по RPC).
2. В сети может находиться несколько машин, которые ответят на этот запрос. Собственно они и отвечают.
3. Клиент принимает ответы и обрабатывает их.

Вот пример конструктора клиентского класса:

```
public RpcClient(IPEndPoint localEndPoint, ProtocolType connectionType, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint)
    {
        LocalEndPoint = localEndPoint;
        RemoteEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;
        ReplyMessages = new Dictionary<EndPoint, RpcReplyMessage>();
        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        xid = (uint)r.Next(65536);
        ConnectionType = connectionType;
        if (RemoteEndPoint.Address == IPAddress.Broadcast && connectionType == ProtocolType.Tcp)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can not create Broadcast TCP connection.");
        switch (connectionType)
        {
            case ProtocolType.Tcp:
                RpcSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, connectionType);
                break;
            case ProtocolType.Udp:
                RpcSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, connectionType);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(connectionType.ToString() + " not supported.");
        }
        if (RemoteEndPoint.Address == IPAddress.Broadcast)
        {
            RpcSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, true);
        }
        RpcSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
        RpcSocket.Bind(LocalEndPoint);
        RpcSocket.Connect(RemoteEndPoint);
    }
```

Вот код метода, делающего вызов программы:

```
public Dictionary<EndPoint, RpcReplyMessage> CallBroadcast(RpcCallMessage callProcedure)
    {
        Dictionary<EndPoint, RpcReplyMessage> replies = new Dictionary<EndPoint, RpcReplyMessage>();
        CallMessage = callProcedure;
        bool waitReplies = true;
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)ipep;
        byte[] mes = callProcedure.ToBytes();
        byte[] finalmes = new byte[sizeof(uint) + mes.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(NetUtils.ToBigEndianBytes(xid), 0, finalmes, 0, 4);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(mes, 0, finalmes, 4, mes.Length);
        switch (ConnectionType)
        {
            case ProtocolType.Tcp:
            case ProtocolType.Udp:
                RpcSocket.SendTo(finalmes, RemoteEndPoint);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception(ConnectionType.ToString() +
                    " protocol have not realization of function Call().");
        }
        if (RemoteEndPoint.Address == IPAddress.Broadcast)
            RpcSocket.Connect(ipep);
        while (waitReplies)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                int recSize = RpcSocket.ReceiveFrom(buff, ref ep);
                if (!(CheckXID(buff) && CheckReceive(buff))) continue;
                recSize -= sizeof(uint);
                byte[] nbuff = new byte[recSize];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buff, sizeof(uint), nbuff, 0, recSize);
                replies.Add(ep, new RpcReplyMessage(nbuff));
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                waitReplies = false;
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        return replies;
    }
```

И вот в этой функции меня больше всего интересует, как принимать данные. Данный код рабочий, но мне не нравится его реализация. И посему есть ряд вопросов. И все они связаны со строчками:

```
if (RemoteEndPoint.Address == IPAddress.Broadcast)
            RpcSocket.Connect(ipep);
```

Если верить msdn, то для работы метода ReceiveFrom() требуется выполнить Bind и не слова не сказано про **Socket.Connect()** для протоколов без установления предварительного соединения. Привязываю я сокет к локальному адресу еще в конструкторе, чтобы жестко задать, с какого адреса и порта отправлять запрос и на какой ждать ответ. Но без **Socket.Connect()** данная функция не работает и на методе **ReceiveFrom()** выдает исключение с текстом:

*Дополнительные сведения: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера*

Ну думаю, может как-то оно так работает. И решил наложить ограничение на порт, чтобы ждать ответ только от портммаппера. Но если я указываю порт не 0, а 111, то выпадает следующее исключение:

*Дополнительные сведения: Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен*

Исходя из всего выше перечисленного рождается мысль, что я делаю что-то не так. Прошу помощи и разъяснения. Хотелось бы без лишних костылей и строчек кода получать ответ от портамапперов, т.е. только с порта отправителя 111.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, видимо требовалось просто свежая голова.
Итак, в конструкторе надо метод Connect() вызывать только в случае подключения по TCP. Т.е. вместо

```
RpcSocket.Connect(RemoteEndPoint);
```

использовать

```
if (ConnectionType == ProtocolType.Tcp) RpcSocket.Connect(RemoteEndPoint);
```

При таком использовании сокет не привязывается к удаленному узлу. Именно по этой причине приходилось переподключать сокет в теле метода.

А в методе вызова процедуры CallBroadcast() часть с TCP-соединением повесить на исключение, и оставить только SendTo() для UDP подключения. А вообще я переписал функцию так, чтобы ее можно было использовать и для единичного вызова. Получилось примерно следующее:

```
public Dictionary<EndPoint, RpcReplyMessage> CallBr(RpcCallMessage callProcedure)
    {
        Dictionary<EndPoint, RpcReplyMessage> replies = new Dictionary<EndPoint, RpcReplyMessage>();
        CallMessage = callProcedure;
        bool waitReplies = ConnectionType == ProtocolType.Tcp ? false : true;
        EndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 111);
        byte[] mes = callProcedure.ToBytes();
        byte[] finalmes = new byte[sizeof(uint) + mes.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(NetUtils.ToBigEndianBytes(xid), 0, finalmes, 0, 4);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(mes, 0, finalmes, 4, mes.Length);
        switch (ConnectionType)
        {
            case ProtocolType.Tcp:
                if (!RpcSocket.Connected) RpcSocket.Connect(RemoteEndPoint);
                RpcSocket.Send(finalmes);
                break;
            case ProtocolType.Udp:
                RpcSocket.SendTo(finalmes, RemoteEndPoint);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception(ConnectionType.ToString() +
                    " protocol have not realization of function Call().");
        }
        do
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                int recSize = RpcSocket.ReceiveFrom(buff, ref ep);
                if (!(CheckXID(buff) && CheckReceive(buff))) continue;
                recSize -= sizeof(uint);
                byte[] nbuff = new byte[recSize];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buff, sizeof(uint), nbuff, 0, recSize);
                replies.Add(ep, new RpcReplyMessage(nbuff));
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                waitReplies = false;
            }
        }
        while (waitReplies);
        return replies;
    }
```

Так же добавил условие на то, чтобы при TCP-подключении сокет принимал данные только однократно.

Касаемо фильтрации по порту отправителя. Видимо это можно устроить только программно проверяя порт, с которого был отправлен ответ.